# Correct way to modify a parents final argument from child in Flutter

Tags: redux, flutter, viewmodel

I am using redux (still learning about it) for my app made in Dart with Flutter. Firstly I am going to explain my code so you can understand better.

I have this card model:

```
class CardModel {
  final List images;
  final int id;
  final AppType category;
  final bool status;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String location;
  final List<String> tags;
  // int userId;

  CardModel(
      {this.images,
      @required this.id,
      @required this.status,
      @required this.category,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.location,
      @required this.tags});

  CardModel copyWith({List images,
       int id,
       bool status,
       AppType category,
       String title,
       String description,
       String location,
       List<String> tags}){
         return CardModel(
           id: id ?? this.id,
           images: images ?? this.images,
           status: status ?? this.status,
           category: category ?? this.category,
           title: title ?? this.title,
           description: description ?? this.description,
           location: location ?? this.location,
           tags: tags ?? this.tags,
         );
       }
}
```

It's immutable because my AppState has instances of this class.

I have the following action:

```
class AddCard {
  final CardModel card;

  AddCard({this.card});
}
```

Secondly, I have an upload page where I have 2 custom stateful widgets, one for the categories and status, and the other one with textfields for title, description, location, tags, etc... See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySa3X.png).

So I am asking myself, how is the correct way of creating the new card?

I've thought these 2 solutions:

1. Create separate variables (which I don't like) for each card attribute in the upload page and passing the needed arguments to my custom widgets (but like some attributes are passed by value, so I must pass voidCallbacks to modify the value in the upload Page?).
2. Create a CardModel empty variable and make use of the copyWith function everytime I want to modify a value. But then if I pass the card value to my custom widgets, they can't assign a new card (widget.card = widget.card.copyWith(fer:ergrgr);) because stateful widgets attributes are final. So I end up passing voidCallbacks again?

I am trying to code as clean as possible, but can't figure out how can I do this... My 2 solutions seems dirty

*SideQuestion: Would make sense to make use of several patterns, like Redux for serializable data and scopeModel for short term data?*